# Neo4j is frequently going down with Out of memory error

Tags: python, memory, neo4j, heap-memory, py2neo

Suddenly Neo4j stops working with following error
Neo4j configuration details as below:

dbms.memory.heap.max_size=8000m

dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=8000m

dbms.memory.pagecache.size=4000m

neo4j_version:3.3.9

we use python as our backend py2neo(3.1.2)

It worked fine for one hour and was down after

Thanks in advance

```
Started.
2020-07-01 08:05:03.514+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
2020-07-01 09:01:59.074+0000 ERROR Unable to reply to request, because the client has closed the connection (Broken pipe).
2020-07-01 09:01:59.077+0000 ERROR Failed to generate JSON output. Closed
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Closed
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:333)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent$Writer.write(WebComponent.java:300)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse$CommittingOutputStream.write(ContainerResponse.java:135)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.TransactionalService$InterruptingOutputStream.write(TransactionalService.java:301)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8Generator._flushBuffer(Utf8Generator.java:1754)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8Generator.flush(Utf8Generator.java:1088)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1615)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.Neo4jJsonCodec.writeValue(Neo4jJsonCodec.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonGeneratorBase.writeObject(JsonGeneratorBase.java:314)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator.writeObjectField(JsonGenerator.java:1090)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.ExecutionResultSerializer.errors(ExecutionResultSerializer.java:317)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionHandle.commit(TransactionHandle.java:177)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.TransactionalService.lambda$executeStatementsAndCommit$1(TransactionalService.java:218)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:57)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1510)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.dbms.AuthorizationEnabledFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationEnabledFilter.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CollectUserAgentFilter.doFilter(CollectUserAgentFilter.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-07-01 09:02:40.014+0000 ERROR Failed to generate JSON output. Closed
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Closed
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:333)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent$Writer.write(WebComponent.java:300)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse$CommittingOutputStream.write(ContainerResponse.java:135)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.TransactionalService$InterruptingOutputStream.write(TransactionalService.java:301)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8Generator._flushBuffer(Utf8Generator.java:1754)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8Generator.flush(Utf8Generator.java:1088)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.ExecutionResultSerializer.finish(ExecutionResultSerializer.j
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@46e77fb7Timer"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "qtp1907591953-29"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "neo4j.PauseMonitor"
2020-07-01 12:06:20.552+0000 WARN  Error for /db/data/transaction/commit Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "neo4j.Scheduled-1"
Exception in thread "ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2020-07-01 14:17:50.476+0000 WARN   Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2020-07-01 14:17:50.476+0000 WARN  Error for /db/data/transaction/commit Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2020-07-01 14:17:50.478+0000 WARN  Unexpected thread death: {} in {}
```

Comment: What queries are you running? How big is your grap,

Comment: even small queries like match(n) return count(n) taking long time and our graph never had more than 100k nodes

Comment: Even on a restart?

Comment: on restart its works but restart is not an option in client environment

Comment: So it seems that there is a problem with some of your queries or connections

Comment: queries are good but when we run same query directly on neo4j browser then also it hangs..something to do with neo4j(3.3 community) version? or the configurations?

Comment: Neo4j Browser usually hangs when you are returning large amounts of data. Try upgrading the Neo4j version, I can't help you if you don't provide any additional information

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217134/discussion-between-ck22-and-tomaz-bratanic).